# Same NetBeans Project from Two Locations

Tags: java, netbeans, version-control, ide

I have a desktop at work, and a laptop at home.  I do not carry my laptop to work.  Is there an accepted way to use the same NetBeans Java project from both machines?

I currently store the project in a Dropbox folder and access it from both machines.  It works 95% of the time, but I occasionally have little glitches (library references, filename case-sensitivity, etc).

I have used a shared network drive, but the latency when compiling and deploying from home isn't acceptable.

I guess I could commit it to SVN everyday, but I probably won't always remember.

Looking to know how others might approach this.

Comment: I use mercurial + bitbucket (free) for my personal projects. It is fully integrated with Netbeans and commits (push) are only one click away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source control is the best option here, You could use some free SVN/GIT service provider too for your private project

**See**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories

Answer (score 2):

Create a bare git repository in your dropbox folder and push/pull from that at home and work. It works very well, and its not that hard to remember. The nice thing about git is that you only need shared disk, which dropbox takes care for you. You don't need a server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm part of a project java and we use a netbeans plugin named [Team Server](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/team-servers.html). This plugin allow you to create a project in java.net and work it under Kenai infrastructure. It is really easy to use.